# Best way to code a webpage/app for a store

Tags: android, ajax, database-connection, webstore

Hello im willing to code a webstore for my sister's business(and of course learning something in the way) im familiar with C++, Java and Html, and a liiitle with sql databases, Im wondering which languages i should be looking to learn in order to make a:

-Server/webstore
-An app (android and ios) who feeds info from the server

Designing the webstore/app its not my problem, but feeding them with user account/items/etc is where im lost.

I hope you can help me thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For a no frills backend, I suggest taking a look into what [Parse](https://parse.com/) and [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) offers. You can then just use REST-ful calls to them. Firebase also support user accounts (even anonymous accounts) + authentications right out of the box.